# Proper way to hide HTML content without manipulating display attribute

Tags: html, css, hide

I have some HTML page content, I dont want to show to the user because its experimental. I tried to wrap the content into an div

```
<div class="experimental">MYCONTENT</div>
```

with the style

```
.experimental {
   display: none
}
```

The Problem is the different styling inside the experimental div. Some elements needs flex, some grid etc. So the default styling of the div destorys my content, when I want to unhide the content.

Now I tried the following self-created solution and want to know if this is a proper way, or if some browsers will have problems with this solution? If I remove the display attribute, the content is displayed like without the experimental wrapper, because it hasn't any default style.

HTML

```
<experimental>MYCONTENT</experimental>
```

CSS

```
experimental {
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but you could wrap your HTML like this:
`<!-- <div class="experimental">MYCONTENT</div> -->` so its commented out, and when you want to edit or see it you can just remove the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your experimental content in a `<template>` like so:

```
<template>MYCONTENT</template>
```

This way you can work on it in your editor, but it does not get displayed to the user.

[See MDN docs for reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)